# Proof for equivalence definition of convergence in the Wasserstein space

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, convergence, wasserstein

From "An Invitation to Statistics in Wasserstein Space" (Victor M. Panaretos and
Yoav Zemel)

Theorem 2.2.1 (Convergence in Wasserstein Space) Let $\mu, \mu_n \in \mathscr{W}_p(\mathscr{X})$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ weakly and $\int_{\mathscr{X}}\|x\|^p \mathrm{~d} \mu_n(x) \rightarrow \int_{\mathscr{X}}\|x\|^p \mathrm{~d} \mu(x)$
2. for any $C>0$ and any continuous $f: \mathscr{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C\left(1+\|x\|^p\right)$ for all $x$,
   $$
   \int_{\mathscr{X}} f(x) \mathrm{d} \mu_n(x) \rightarrow \int_{\mathscr{X}} f(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)$$

I am trying to prove this equivalence where $\mathscr{X}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mu$ is a measure related to a continuous distribution function and I denote by $X$ and $X_n$ the random vectors related to the measures $\mu_n(x), \mu(x)$.

$$
\int_{\mathscr{X}} f(x)  \mathrm{d} \mu_n(x) \leq \int_{\mathscr{X}} |f(x)|  \mathrm{d} \mu_n(x) \leq C\int_{\mathscr{X}} 1  \mathrm{d} \mu_n(x) + C\int_{\mathscr{X}}  \|x\|^p \mathrm{d} \mu_n(x) =  C\int_{\mathscr{X}} 1  \mathrm{d} \mu_n(x)  + E[ \|X_n\|^p ]
$$

where the last term converges because of (2.) and I guess that the first term should converge because of (1.) but I am not sure why.